# Optimizing operation on nested dictionary

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I have a nested dict that contains a lot of items which I encrypt and save it to a file, when I mean encrypt, I am using aes to encrypt the string of both outer keys, and inner keys and inner values.

The dict is something like the size of this

```
data = {str(x): {str(y): str(y) for y in range(800)} for x in range(50)}
```

And the operation will be something like:

```
def e(): pass #Encryption method

encrypted = {}
for outkey, outvalue in data.items():
        encrypted[e(outkey)] = {e(k): e(v) for k, v in outvalue.items()}
```

I tried turning the inner dict keys and values for numpy array and performing the encryption that way instead of iterating but timing it says it takes the same or longer... Is there any other way to optimize it (not including multiprocessing or multi threading)?

Comment: Can you post the encryption func, the actual time, and the expected time? Also what kind of sizes do the strings have? Stupid question: you mentioned `str(y): str(y)`, is this the real case? The keys and values are the same?

Comment: Why can't you use multiprocessing ? And if you cannot use a lib that encrypt for you (and therefore, **probably** do it better than you do)... I don't know how you could do it. :/

Comment: which version of python? If 2 : use iteritems()

Comment: To answer all of your questions, 1. I can't post the encryption function because it will defeat the purpose, however the encryption is using CryptoCipher so it is fairly optimized, the problem is that the dictionary is very large. 2. str(y): str(y) is not the case, the keys aren't the same as the values, the dictionary I wrote here is a simulation and testing dictionary that is the same structure and roughly the same size... 3. I am already using multiprocessing to speed it up, but I want a solution for slower computers... 4. last of all, I am using python 3.7

Comment: @David47 security by obscurity often isn't the best practice. If the safety of your algorithm depends on nobody knowing its implementation, then its not very safe.

Comment: @DillonDavis well, I know this isn't the best but for an app only I use it will be enough... in any case, the encryption isn't my problem, the question is about optimizing an operation on the whole dictionary, it could've been any other operation and the question will have stayed...